# SwiftUI images as custom "radio" buttons

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to have a simple Color Picker with a few pre-defined colours. The user should only be able to pick one of the colors.

It should work like a "radio" input where when one color is selected, the other colors uncheck.

I decided a decent approach would be to have images that use the system "circle.fill", and, "checkmark.circle.fill" for the selected item. I would just set the `foregroundColor` for each to their corresponding `.color`.

I'm having a rough time figuring out the logic for this though. I know I can create a simple View for the images themselves and pass the `.color` to each one, but how would I go about ensuring only 1 image is "checked" at once, and obtaining the value from the "checked" image so it can be passed to Core Data?

I guess I can use state `$var` which changes, but how do I unselect all of the other images when one is selected? Should I put the images in an array or something? I'm lost.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are thinking the right way, but the color needs to be changed using accentColor as that's the way to change button's color:

Start by defining a CheckBox, which will be initilised with a color and will also hold a binding to it's parent view's selected color.

```
struct CheckBox: View {

    @Binding var selectedColor: Color?
    var color: Color

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { self.selectedColor = self.color }) {
            Image(systemName: self.selectedColor == color ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle.fill")
        }   .accentColor(self.color)
    }
}
```

Tapping on the button will set button's color to be the selected one in it's parent view.
Next  you need to group the CheckBoxes into another view which holds the selected color as it's state:

```
struct RadioButtons: View {

    let colors: [Color] = [.purple,
                           .red,
                           .orange,
                           .yellow,
                           .green,
                           .blue]

    @State var selectedColor: Color?

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(colors, id:  \.description) { color in
                CheckBox(selectedColor: self.$selectedColor, color: color)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here it is:

[image: radio buttons]

Comment: Thank you! I actually JUST finished coding something similar, but this helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Store the selected index in a @State var. When displaying the rows, check if the current row index is the selected one, if so, use the check mark image, use the circle otherwise.